# Text wrap in matrix context

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

Before I use the matrix facility. I can wrap text inside a box simply by specifying the `align=left` property then `\\`

However, in the matrix context, this seems not working. I want the graph like this
[image]

However the following code compiles fail on `This is \\ node D` under matrix

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, matrix}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{underscore}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \tikzset{myrect/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, align=left, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black}}

    \node [myrect] (a) {This is node A};
    \node [myrect, below = of a] (b) {This is \\ node B};

    \matrix (matrix1) [below = of b, nodes = {myrect}, matrix of nodes, row sep=1cm] {
        This is node C \\
        {This is \\ node D} \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The line wrapping under matrix only works when I am adding things like `text width = 3cm`, but this seems redundant to `align=left`.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you really want a matrix or by chance a `chain`?

Comment: I need to draw flowchart for some algorithms. Sometimes multi row and multi column to illustrate different code execution path. This is why I use the matrix.

Comment: Hmmh, even then I am not 100% sure a matrix is the best choice (but your question is good regardless of that, that's why I upvoted it).

Comment: Yeah, if there is alternative way to do so that will be also great :)

Comment: Well, the question is to do *what*. What kind of flowchart do you need? In general, `positioning`, which you load and use is already a good choice IMHO, and `chain`s can be helpful, too. (Again, the question by itself is interesting, and as of now I don't have a good answer. OK, that does not mean much, maybe @percusse will solve it ;-)

Comment: For example a function implementation is using `switch...case...case...` control structure, I will use a matrix with row number equal to program branches, then use chain to connect them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\matrix (matrix1) [below = of b, nodes = {myrect}, matrix of nodes, row sep=1cm] {
    This is node C \\
    \shortstack{This is \\ node D}\\};
```

[image]

Comment: this works except the text `align` changed from `left` to `center`.

Comment: use `\shortstack[l]{...}`

Comment: Thank you @Herbert. Seems I can remove the `align=left` when defining the `myrect` style